# Stop OneDrive share for a Desktop subfolder

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, onedrive

I am planning on using this PC (windows 10) with virtual machines. This can take up several hundreds of GBs, and my OneDrive cannot store that. I plan to keep them on my Desktop, but it is being synced by OneDrive. Is it possible to turn off sharing for just ONE folder that has my Virtual Machines, and not the whole thing?

thanks

Comment: I have One Drive here and I have 150 GB of Virtual Machines. I do not put Virtual Machines in my One Drive.  They do need to be local to the machine or on a very (very) fast network. So just do not use One Drive for your VM's

Comment: I'm not trying to, I just want to use a folder in my desktop and want it to not sync @John

Comment: But, I still want to sync everything else on my desktop...

Comment: I use a folder C:\Virtual Machines for this

Comment: So basically its not possible @John ?

Comment: Just keep VM's away from Sync'd folders. That will work better for you

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the root of the shared OneDrive folder (Desktop in you case) or on any sub-folders and select "Chose OneDrive folders to sync". Then you get a dialog where you can specifically say which folders, sub-folders should be synced or not...

**Selective OneDrive**

[image: IMG:]

***Edit:*** if you don't see that option on folder's context menu, then right-click on the OneDrive tray icon, select Settings > Account and then you should see "Choose Folders" [image: FromTrayIcon]
Also see [Choose which OneDrive folders to sync](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85)

Comment: It does not show the option to choose onedrive folders to sync

Comment: See then the other way: from tray icon > Settings > Account > Choose folders

Comment: Just realised that "Chose OneDrive folders to sync" doesn't appear if OneDrive app is **not** running: so in all cases (from folder context menu or from tray icon), you have to start OneDrive first.